# tabulator performs unwanted scrolling on row click

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I have a tabulator table with a defined height inside a React component.
If I scroll to the bottom of the table and click a row, the table scrolls back to the top.
I can even see the scrollVertical() callback occurs with a value of "0".

How can I prevent this unwanted scrolling?

Ideally, I want the scroll to remain unchanged & the selected row to remain highlighted until a different row is clicked.

Here is the relevant code.

```
  componentDidMount() {  
    this.tableInst = new Tabulator(this.tableRef, {
      layout: "fitDataFill",
      data: [],
      dataTree: true,
      dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
      selectable: 1,
      selectablePersistence: false,
      columns: [{ title: "Report", field: "reportName" }],
      rowClick: (e, row) => this.handleRowClick(e, row),
      scrollVertical: (top) => this.scrollVertical(top),
    });
  }

  handleRowClick = (e, row) => {
    var data = row.getData();
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty("_children")) {
      this.setState({ flavor: data.flavor });
    }
  };

  scrollVertical = (top) => {
    console.log("scroll: " + top);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the unwanted scroll-to-top.

I was performing a table.setData() during componentDidUpdate().

Once the table.setData() was removed

- the table no longer did the scroll-to-top
- the selected row remained highlighted

Everything working as expected!

Comment: Not sure if you need to update the data or not, but `table.replaceData()` will replace the data and retain the scroll position and I believe the highlighted row.  http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/update#alter-replace